# The Mystery of the Missing Architectures

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, arm

I'm following a tutorial on building a multi-platform iOS framework -- it mentions these architecture names:

[image: Screenshot 1: Tutorial Page]

In my Xcode build Settings, I set my architectures like so:

- $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
- i386
- x86_64
- arm7s
- armv7
- armv7s

However, upon building I get the following errors:

[image]

Anyone have a clue why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `arm7s`, the only one I know of thats similar is `armv7s`. 
Remove the mention of arm7s and try rebuild.

The particular [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios) you're looking at is incorrect. The supported iOS device architectures are:

- `armv7`
- `armv7s`
- `arm64`

For the simulator:

- `i386`

There's an [Apple Reference Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW51) for build settings that makes a mention of some of these. It hasn't been updated since 2010, so theres no armv7s or armv64, but you can see what else has been supported. No mention of arm7, or arm7s.